# How can I copy a templated instance with a virtual base class?

Tags: c++, templates

TL;DR
how can I copy the last element of a vector, given that this element is an instance of a template class which is also derived from a virtual base class?

---

I want to create a vector which will act as an undo stack. the stack should hold float and string based objects (and possibly other types). It might contain all floats, all strings or a combination of both.
When a float or a string is added for the first time, I want to add a copy of it to the stack.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Base
{
...
virtual bool func1() = 0;
}
```

a derived class with a template argument

```
template<typename T>
class derived : public base {...}
```

and these two

```
class foo : public derived<float>
class bar : public derived<string>
```

in main:

```
std::vector<Base> stack;
if (condition) 
stack.push_back(new foo())
else
stack.push_back(new bar())
```

if `stack.back().func1()==true` add another `foo` or `bar`.
`func1` is implemented in `foo` and `bar` and returns true if it’s the first `foo` or `bar` in the stack

```
if (stack.back().func1())  
 //do something like
 //stack.push_back(new foo) if stack.back() is a foo
 //stack.push_back(new bar) if stack.back() is a bar
```

Now, I can’t do `stack.push_back(new Base)` because it has a virtual function. for the same reason I can’t make a copy of `stack.back()`.
I also can’t do `stack.push_back(new drived<T>)` because I don’t know that `T` is.
I definitely don’t want to hardcode `new foo`, `new bar`, `string` or `float` because I want to keep the code generic for future derived classes.

So how can I copy the last element of a vector, or add a new element of the same kind, given that this element is a template class which is derived from a virtual base class?

Comment: You have to use a `std::vector<Base*>`, or better `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` for this to work. Normally this problem is solved by making a virtual `clone` method that each derived class can override.

Comment: The templating and indirection through an intermediate class makes no difference - you solve this in exactly the same way as if `foo` and `bar` inherited directly from `Base`.

Comment: Thanks @super, this is the kind of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, it's done by adding `clone` method to the `Base`:

```cpp
struct Base {
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

CRTP can be used to automate overriding this method here:

```cpp
template<class Child> struct Clonable: Base {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const final {
        auto &asChild = *static_cast<Child const *>(this);
        return std::make_unique<Child>(asChild);
    }
};

struct Foo: Clonable<Foo> {};
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, thank you, missed that.